# MySQL - After Insert Trigger that updates two tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-update

I have a problem with a MySQL Trigger.
I have 3 tables **Customers**, **Products** and **Sales**.
In **Sales** I reference **customer** and **product** and I want to update the some counts on **Products** and **Customers** after a new sale is inserted.
The following trigger fails to update both tables... I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER OnSalesInsert AFTER INSERT ON Sales
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 UPDATE Products SET Products.sold=Products.sold+NEW.amount WHERE Products.id=NEW.product_id;
 UPDATE Customers SET Customers.amount=Customers.amount+NEW.amount WHERE Customers.id=NEW.customer_id;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: is there some error message? or log?

Comment: No, its just fails... In the php, mysql_query($sql,$con) returns false and mysql_error() returns nothing. If $sql is a multi-insert statement, only the first row is inserted on Sales, I suppose due the trigger fail.

Comment: Are you sure that ´sold´ and ´amount´ fields are numeric types to use + operator? If it is text, you need to use ´CONCAT´ function

Comment: Yes, they are all INTs. In the above trigger, if I left only one of the UPDATE clauses (no matter which one), it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `OnSalesInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Sales` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

       UPDATE Products 
       SET sold = sold + new.amount 
       WHERE id = new.product_id; 

       UPDATE Customers 
       SET amount = amount + new.amount 
       WHERE id = new.customer_id;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger UpdateAvail after insert on product_details
for each row
Begin
 Declare a1 INT;
Declare d1 VARCHAR(1);
Declare d2 VARCHAR(100);
Select count(0) INTO a1 from prod_available where P_Id=new.P_Id;
Select P_Name,P_Brand INTO d1,d2 from product where P_Id=new.P_Id;
IF a1>0 THEN
Update prod_available set P_quantity=P_quantity+new.quantity where P_Id=new.P_Id;
ELSE
insert into prod_available (P_Id,P_Name,P_Brand,P_quantity)   values                     (new.P_Id,d1,d2,new.quantity);
  END IF;
  END;
  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Try to add a brief explanation, it will help a lot.